# Changing buttons of system On-Screen Navigation Bar in Android

Tags: android

When the soft-input keyboard is shown, on-screen navigation bar has the "back" button pointing down.

When I show some dialog or fragment, I would like to do the same. Is there a way in Android to change the icon of the button in on-screen navigation bar?